# Python - bulk promote variables to parent scope

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python 2.7, I want to run:

$ ./script.py initparms.py

This is a trick to supply a parameter file to script.py, since initparms.py contains several python variables e.g.

```
Ldir =   '/home/marzipan/jelly'
LMaps = True
# etc.
```

script.py contains:

```
X = __import__(sys.argv[1])
Ldir = X.Ldir
LMaps = X.Lmaps
# etc.
```

I want to do a bulk promotion of the variables in X so they are available to script.py, without spelling out each one in the code by hand.

Things like

```
import __import__(sys.argv[1])
```

or

```
from sys.argv[1] import *
```

don't work. Almost there perhaps... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @downvoter -- Care to explain?  I think that this is reasonably clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a one-liner:

```
globals().update(__import__(sys.argv[1]).__dict__)
```

Comment: Is this safer, presumably, than using execfile()?

Comment: @user1021819 -- Nope.  This isn't any safer than `execfile`.  It can still easily run untrusted code.

Comment: @user1021819 - This has the same risk as execfile. The difference is that the script will be in the list of imported modules and won't be re-executed if it is also imported somewhere else. I doubt it makes any difference to you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile):

```
execfile(sys.argv[1])
```

Of course, the usual warnings with `exec` or `eval` apply (Your script has no way of knowing whether it is running trusted or untrusted code).

My suggestion would be to not do what you're doing and instead use `configparser` and handling the configuration though there.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and warnings!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import os
import imp
import sys

try:
    module_name = sys.argv[1]
    module_info = imp.find_module(module_name, [os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))] + sys.path)
    module_properties = imp.load_module(module_name, *module_info)
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    try:
        attrlist = module_properties.__all__
    except AttributeError:
        attrlist = dir(module_properties)
    for attr in attrlist:
        if attr.startswith('__'):
            continue
        globals()[attr] = getattr(module_properties, attr)
```

Little complicated, but gets the job done.